# Basic Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I just finished a course about systems of linear équations and I'm trying to do some exercises.
Here is the system to solve using Gaussian elimination:

$$
\begin{cases}
-5x-2y+z=a \\
-4x-4y-4z=b \\
x-2y-5z=c
\end{cases}
$$

Here is what I did:
$$\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x-2y-5z=c \\
-4x-4y-4z=b \\
-5x-2y+z=a
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x-2y-5z=c \\
-12y-24z=b+4c \\
-12y-24z=a+5c 
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x-2y-5z=c \\
y+2z=\frac{-b-4c}{12} \\
y+2z=\frac{-a-5c}{12} 
\end{cases}
$$
But what to do now? I don't know how to proceed because I can't use y nor z as a pivot element.
Maple tells me that there isn't any solution, but I don't know how to prove that...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended up with the following:

$\begin{cases}
x-2y-5z=c, \\
y+z=\frac{-b-4c}{12}, \\
y+z=\frac{-a-5c}{12}. 
\end{cases}$

Notice the two last equations. They each say that $y+z$ is equal to two things, so these two things better not be different, because otherwise there are no solutions.

So a necessary condition for there to be any solutions is that $\frac{-b-4c}{12}=\frac{-a-5c}{12}$ (and let's say that their common value is $d$). Thus, you have the two equations

$\begin{cases}
x-2y-5z=c, \\
y+z=d.
\end{cases}$

You may notice that you are not quite done with your Gaussian elimination. It is possible for you to eliminate the $y$ in the top equation by using the bottom equation.